# QT5 support animated png (apng)

Tags: qt, png, apng

I'm curious if QT5 supports animated PNG (APNG)?
If Yes, how will work with it?
I know it support animated gif and I have to use QMovie to display animated gif, is that the same for apng ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt5 cannot play apng, but mng is possible. QMovie like you know it from animated gifs.

Comment: It seems that QMovie doesn't support mng by default anymore...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [QtApng repo on github](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtApng). Haven't tried it, but it might help.

Answer (score -1):

[Qt5.15](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html)+ does support animated WebP images by default.